# Some lodash functions aren't defined

Tags: javascript, lodash

Some of the lodash function gives 'not a function error'.
For example: `_.minBy`, `_.maxBy`, `_.cloneDeep` etc.

Other functions like `_.map`, `_.clone` etc. are working fine. I tried with lodash 4 and lodash 3.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.1.0/lodash.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var drinks = [
  { 'name': 'Coke', 'quantity': 2 },
  { 'name': 'Red Bull', 'quantity': 6 }
];
var currentDrinks = _.map(drinks, 'name');
console.log(currentDrinks);
// → [‘Coke’, ‘Red Bull’]
var a = [{"type":"exam","score":47.67196715489599},{"type":"quiz","score":41.55743490493954},{"type":"homework","score":70.4612811769744},{"type":"homework","score":48.60803337116214}];

const b = _.minBy(a, 'score');
console.log(b);

</script>
```

Here `_.map` works and `_.minBy` not working. Which version of lodash I should use to support for `_.minBy` and `_.deepClone`?

Comment: Are you using npm? If so, what's the output of `npm list lodash`? Are you doing any transpiling / bundling? And where did the error occur? In Node.js (and which version) or a modern browser?

Comment: I am using CDN and modern browser.

Comment: Here _.map works and _.minBy not working.
Which version of lodash I should use to support for _.minBy and _.deepClone.

Comment: Btw, `_.deepClone` doesn't exist. There's only `_.cloneDeep`. (since version 1.0.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works perfectly with lodash 4:

```js
var drinks = [
  { 'name': 'Coke', 'quantity': 2 },
  { 'name': 'Red Bull', 'quantity': 6 }
];
var currentDrinks = _.map(drinks, 'name');
console.log(currentDrinks); // → [‘Coke’, ‘Red Bull’]
var a = [
  {"type":"exam","score":47.67196715489599},
  {"type":"quiz","score":41.55743490493954},
  {"type":"homework","score":70.4612811769744},
  {"type":"homework","score":48.60803337116214}
];
const b = _.minBy(a, 'score');
console.log(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

`.minBy` and `.maxBy` have been introduced in version 4.0.0. Just use a version higher than this.

**Edit**: In the file you uploaded, you aren't specifying the whole library. You are just loading the core. (In your question you referenced however the correct file, but the wrong version.)

Change:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me to solve the issue.I 'Run code snippet' and understand it works fine.Is there anything I am doing wrong in my local machine and causing error.  I am running whole script as html.

Comment: Are you maybe defining multiple `<script />` tags? Maybe you are somewhere loading an older versions, which overrides the new one. If you can't figure out what's going on, just post the whole file.